Taskbar not visible after exiting TTY mode
After inadvertently entering TTY mode and returning to the graphical user interface, I noticed a few issues:

The taskbar no longer appears when I press the 'Windows' key; only full-screen applications are displayed.
Files previously visible on the desktop screen are no longer displayed, although they remain in the desktop folder.

I would appreciate assistance in resolving these issues to restore the usual desktop environment.
Image of screen now:

